# Access a jpg in an Image folder of a project

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on a program that generates a PDF using a third party .dll.  I am trying to add a header image to the PDF by sending in the string path of the jpg (Logo.jpg) in the project that is in a folder I created (Images), but it is not working using code like this..

```
PDFPage.AddHeaderImage("String path of the jpg in the project") 
PDFPage.AddHeaderImage("~/Images/Logo.jpg))
```

There is a "could not find file" exception.

It works fine when I point to a file on my computer like this...

```
PDFpage.AddHeaderImage("C:/Source Code/Source/images/Logo.jpg");
```

But, I do not want to point to a file on my computer.  I want to point to a the file in the Images folder in my project where I put Logo.jpg.  I also put the image in Resources, but do not know what the string would be to access it.  Either way would be fine.

the .AddHeaderImage is expecting a string path.

Comment: To access the resources `Your.NameSpace.Properties.Resources.Logo`

Answer (score 1):

If you set `Build Action = Content` and `Copy To Output Directory = Copy Always` on the properties of the image file in Solution Explorer in Visual Studio, then the image file will be output to your bin folder along with the compiled application. You can then use a path relevant to the executable.

```
PDFPage.AddHeaderImage("Images/Logo.jpg));
```

Comment: You probably mean to set the `Build Action` to `Content` and `Copy to Output Directory` to something else than `Do not copy`.

Comment: I do. I was trying to recall it from memory. Thanks.